# why dot inside square brackets doesn't match any character?

Tags: java, regex

Why this `[.]+` Java regular expression doesn't match my `"foo"` text, while `.+` matches perfectly (tested [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html))?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`[.]` is equivalent to escaping the `.` (dot) character, i.e. `\\.`.

Once the character appears in a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html), it loses its status as a special character.

As `foo` doesn't contain any dots, nothing is matched. `.+`, on the other hand, is a wildcard greedy expression that matches everything.

Comment: Do you have a link for this? I always used square brackets for ranges, not for escaping.

Comment: "Remember that the dot is not a metacharacter inside a character class, so we do not need to escape it with a backslash." - [source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

Comment: @yegor256 the brackets mean "character class", which can _contain_ ranges of characters, but most characters are interpreted literally in a character class - unless they are escaped themselves - I recommend [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) for learning regular expressions (I learned most of what I know from there)

Comment: From the javadoc linked by StephenC: *Note that a different set of metacharacters are in effect inside a character class than outside a character class. For instance, the regular expression `.` loses its special meaning inside a character class, while the expression - becomes a range forming metacharacter.*

Comment: @yegor256 and one more thing wonderful about Java regex is that it treats _both_ `[` and `]` as special characters in a character class, requiring both to be escaped to be interpreted literally - most other regex flavors only treat `]` as a special character. Thanks Java!